# Operation result with one of the variables null (empty)

Tags: sas

I am converting SAS code to C# code and I don't have platform to run SAS code, what I have only source code, and I have line of the code in SAS where one of the variables is empty and another is not and I would like to know what would be result of y in following operation.

```
x = .
y = 5 - x
```

x is empty (null)
Please advice.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the result of y will be . (empty) 
When you perform an operation with an empty(null) variable the result is null.